# Code stops executing prematurely

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem.
I have posted my javascript code here: http://pastebin.com/9vWgSWEz
The problem I am encountering is that the code quits executing after it assigns `var OurLink = link;` It pops-up 'link assigned' and then it quits executing.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `Math.floor`, not `Math.Floor`.

Check your errors.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: Learn how to check javascript errors in your browser. Always have the javascript console open when doing development work.